# chrome-extension: Accessing a host without adding it to the host_permissions field in the manifest file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

According to chrome extensions documentation, to access a host from an extension it must be added to the host_permissions field of the manifest file, however, I'm able to access API's  (whose response headers contain 'allow-access-control-origin: *') which I haven't added to the manifest file, I don't understand why? is this because of 'allow-access-control-origin: *' header?

Manifest file:

```
{
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon2.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker":  "background.js"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "109",
  "name": "cryptocurrency price alerts",
  "description": "Set price alerts",
  "version": "4.1",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "author": "kaleem",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage", "notifications"
  ]
}
```

API's I was able to access:

https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices

https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx

Comment: `host_permissions` is needed to make cross-origin requests, whereas allow-access-control-origin: `*` makes the server act as though it's same-origin from the viewpoint of access control.